# Dynamic styling of Crosstab cel

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

In a crosstab cel i need to style text looking something outside the crosstab data (something like a third dimension of crosstab)

example data (articles):

```
|name|color|kind    |qty|
-------------------------
|A1  |red  |standard|1  |
|A1  |green|extra   |5  |
|A1  |green|extra   |10 |
|A2  |red  |standard|2  |
|A2  |green|standard|5  |
```

Crosstab output:

```
|  |red|green|
--------------
|A1|1  |15   |
|A2|2  |5    |
```

I'd like to change style of the 15 cel beacuse it has some "extra" kind article inside.
I wrote a Style rule based on field but there is a report error "Field not found".

Answer (score 0):

I added a second Measure on the Crosstab, evaluating if data comes from "extra" records.
Now i can build the style rule using the second Measure of the Crosstab

[image]